# Why every element color are different?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    x:Name="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="20" Width="100" Content="Click Me" Name="Button1" />
            <Menu x:Name="Menu1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem91" Header="London" Height="40" Width="145" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem92" Header="Paris" Height="40" Width="145" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem93" Header="Berlin" Height="40" Width="145" />
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

vb.net

```
Class MainWindow
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(196, 154, 3, 255))
    Menu1.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(196, 154, 3, 255))
    MenuItem91.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(196, 154, 3, 255))
    MenuItem92.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(196, 154, 3, 255))
End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see above code I put **Color.FromArgb(196, 154, 3, 255))** for every element.

Why every element color are different?

Question picture;

https://prnt.sc/ii64h4

Comment: Maybe because you are using transparency in your SolidBrush. (the A part in ARGB, your first argument: 196)

Comment: Aye Run CMD just beat me too it..

Comment: @RunCMD I dont understand what you mean. If 196 is same for every element why results are different?

Comment: @KenKeniee think of 3 partly trasparent green glass sheets. If you hold them partly in front of each other, the part where they overlap will be more green then the other parts where just line shines trrough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using transparency in your Solidbrush:

```
New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(196, 154, 3, 255))
```

The first argument of this Color.FromArgb method is hte alpha channel, this means the background will 'shine trough your'. In other words the background will be partly visible.

If you want just a solid color, just use the same method with only the 3 RGB arguments:

```
New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(154, 3, 255))
```

This will create a brush with full opacity.

...EDIT......

[image]

Look at the above image. All rectangles have the same RGB value or color, but the left ones have transparency, or 10% opacity. If you place them on top of each other, you get 'different colors', although they have the same RGB values...

Comment: This is not answer of my question. My question is why colors look different even Alpha is the same?

Comment: In the image above, left, all rectangles have the same Alpha. This results in different colors however...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now.